# How to verify legit PayPal buyer?

Tags: paypal

I'm using Paypal Express checkout to get paid.
Now I would like to verify the buyer is legit.

The customer selects his shipping address on my site and this address will be sent to Paypal.

I first check the payer is verified.
Now I want to check that the shipping address the customer selected is confirmed by PayPal.

My question is: can i count on PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS field?

Are there any other checks you recommend me testing before approving the order?

10x

Answer (score 0):

If `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS` is `Confirmed`, it means that PayPal has taken extra steps to confirm that the address most likely belongs to the buyer (or the buyer is associated with that address in some fashion).  In this case, PayPal will usually cover you (the merchant) under the Seller Protection Policy -- e.g., as long as you ship it to that address using a traceable carrier, PayPal will insure you against unauthorized purchase ("I didn't buy this") claims as well as item not received ("I never got this") claims.  It's probably about the best indicator you're going to get that the transaction is legit.

However, keep in mind that the final determination as to whether PayPal will cover you under the Seller Protection Policy is made when you call DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  If `PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY` comes back as `Eligible`, you're covered.